# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I get this error message

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first"

Please help me 
My code is:

```
Public Sub update_qty(ByVal qry1 As String) 
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader 'SQLiteDataReader 
        Dim comm As MySqlCommand 'SQLiteCommand 


        Try

            comm = New MySqlCommand(qry1, conn)
            dr = comm.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Do While dr.Read()
            exe_query("call cargosys.paymentsAdd('" & var1 & "', " & dr("inNo") & ")")
        Loop

        dr.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub exe_query(ByVal qry As String) As String 

        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand 

        Try
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(qry, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)      
        End Try

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your code open a `DataReader` and then execute the `SqlCommand` when the `DataReader` read

Try to change this line:

```
 dr = comm.ExecuteReader()
```

to:

```
 dr = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
```

More: [DataReader CommandBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx)

Or change your connection string to enable MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets).
This setting will allow for the retrieval of multiple forward-only, read-only result sets on the same connection.

For example :

```
connectionString=
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Northwind.MDF;
Integrated Security=True;
User Instance=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

More: [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf.aspx)

**EDIT**

Since MARS keyword is not supported, try to change your code to this:

```
Public Sub update_qty(ByVal qry1 As String) 
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader 'SQLiteDataReader 
        Dim comm As MySqlCommand 'SQLiteCommand 


        Try

            comm = New MySqlCommand(qry1, conn)
            dr = comm.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Dim myList As New List(Of String)

        Do While dr.Read()
            myList.Add("call cargosys.paymentsAdd('" & var1 & "', " & dr("inNo") & ")")
        Loop

        dr.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub exe_query(myList As List(Of String)) 

        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand 

        For Each query As String In myList
            Try
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)      
            End Try
        Next

 End Sub
```

Instead to doing `DataReader.Read`->`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` simultaneously, this code will be read all the data first and then run `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: I am using Mysql, that keyword not supported

Comment: @imsome1 if this answer solved your problem, support Iswanto San by marking this as the accepted answer (press the tick next to the answer).

Comment: "DataReader already active on this command" still getting this error.